# Overriding Events in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Is there a way to translate this code in VB? Most of it is easy, but I can't figure out a way to override the event handler.

```
public class MTObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{

    public MTObservableCollection()
    {
        _DispatcherPriority = DispatcherPriority.DataBind;
    }
    public MTObservableCollection(DispatcherPriority dispatcherPriority)
    {
        _DispatcherPriority = dispatcherPriority;
    }
    private DispatcherPriority _DispatcherPriority;

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var eh = CollectionChanged;
        if (eh != null)
        {
            Dispatcher dispatcher = (from NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in eh.GetInvocationList()
                                     let dpo = nh.Target as DispatcherObject
                                     where dpo != null
                                     select dpo.Dispatcher).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dispatcher != null && dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, (Action)(() => OnCollectionChanged(e)));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in eh.GetInvocationList())
                    nh.Invoke(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no point in overriding the event.

Comment: @nobugz, then show me how to gain access to underlying delegate so the rest of the code can be translated.

Comment: Use RaiseEvent in VB.NET code, no need for the foreach() loop.  The C# programmer didn't understand events very well.

Comment: @nobugz: Read the code. It doesn't just raise an event, it analyzes the objects attached to the event to determine which thread to raise the event on.

Comment: I can't answer the question other than to say "use c#", which is not helpful, because I don't know how to access the invocation list in VB in this case; however, I prefer the "SynchronizingObject" pattern to this "figure out at runtime" approach. Have and overloaded constructor accept an optional synchronizing object of type DispatcherObject and then test that (and use that) for thread UI marshaling for all subscribers like the System.Timers.Timer does. Just a thought, for what its worth.

Comment: It is even a mistake to override events in C# see note in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx

Comment: @Wilhelm, Mind placing that in the answer's box so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is even an error to override events in C#. The [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx) says:

> Do not declare virtual events in a
>   base class and override them in a
>   derived class. The C# compiler does
>   not handle these correctly in
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and it is
>   unpredictable whether a subscriber to
>   the derived event will actually be
>   subscribing to the base class event.

I wonder why a framework class breaks this rule, or even why the compiler allows it.

Comment: WPF is a strange beast and does a lot of things that don't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Rewrite Edit:**

A conversation that figures it's a compiler implementation snafu and suggests workarounds:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/ce30ceed-c260-4d99-b96d-5b7179466be8

This is my (semi) final answer.

Comment: Code that can't possibly compile isn't much use to me. The line "Public Overloads Overrides Event CollectionChanged As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler" is not valid VB syntax.

Comment: Can you tell I don't do much VB. You're correct my original answer wouldn't compile so I have replaced it with something else instead of deleting altogether.

Comment: Thanks, that was a rather interesting discussion.