# Is it really an error to override events in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, coding-style, event-handling

I read in this question: [Overriding Events in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269113/overriding-events-in-vb)

> It is even an error to override events in C#. The C# Programming Guide says:
>       Do not declare virtual events in a base class and override them in a derived class. The C# compiler does not handle these correctly in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and it is unpredictable whether a subscriber to the derived event will actually be subscribing to the base class event.
>   I wonder why a framework class breaks this rule, or even why the compiler allows it.

I can't understand why it's a mistake to override events. Sure an inheriting class can always monitor the base class event and take it's own actions afterwards, but what if it wants to ensure that it is the first event observer to see the event? What it it wants to decide to swallow the event under certain conditions? What's wrong with doing something like this:

```
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VerifyActiveCountMatches();
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        InvokePropertyChanged("Count");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an *error* to do so - but it may well be a bad design decision. There's a big difference; the compiler won't let you get away with an error, but it rarely criticizes your design.

The code you've shown for `OnCollectionChanged` does *not* override an event - it overrides the method which *raises* the event. That's an entirely different matter. An event is something like:

```
// "Field-like" event - the compiler implements the add/remove and
// creates a backing field.
public event EventHandler Click;
```

or

```
// Manually-implemented event; you write the add/remove yourself, and
// create a separate backing variable if necessary.
public event EventHandler Click
{
    add { ... }
    remove { ... }
}
```

These are the pieces of code which handle the subscription and unsubscription - and it's *these* that the advice is saying you shouldn't override. You'd rarely *want* to, and as the quoted text says, there are plenty of situations where it wouldn't do what you wanted it to anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That is not overriding the event, you are overriding the event invoker there (possibly a handler, but that pattern usually denotes a protected member that is used to invoke the event handler).

Overriding an event would look something like:

```
public override event EventHandler CollectionChanged;
```

Comment: In the same vein, is there anything wrong with overriding the event invoker?

Comment: Nope, as long as you remember to call the base member (otherwise it probably wouldn't be invoked).

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2007/11/26/virtual-events-in-c.aspx) blog:

"Using a virtual field-like event in the parent class and not changing any of its behavior in the overriding derived class is not necessary. You can simply omit the override in the derived class to get the desired behavior."

If you aren't changing behavior then why make it virtual? As pointed out, this is different than overriding the method that raises the event.